# Recover whole search pattern for substitute command

Tags: search, substitute, register

Sometimes I type a long substitute command

```
/%s/foo/bar.../
```

and while I am typing it or only after hiting enter
I notice that I have mistakenly
used a the search key (`/`) instead of the ex-command key (`:`).

To fix it,

1. If I have already pressed enter, I bring back the search string
   with `/<C-P>`.
2. Use the mouse to copy from `%s` to the end of the search string
   to the primary selection.
3. `<ESC>:<C-R>*` and the search string is now a proper substitute command.

Or I simply type it all again if it is short enough.

Is there some simpler way to do it? I know about the `/` register, but `<C-R>/` only recovers `%s`.

Comment: You could use `q/` to retrieve the whole thing.

Comment: @BLayer Indeed, we found that `q/` out at the same time!

Comment: +1 for _our_ idea. :D

Comment: Did this get featured in hot network questions or something? @Quasimodo did you think that what is essentially a question about user error would garner this much interest? :)

Comment: @BLayer As per the history, it did. I think the answer is twofold: (1) This question attracted many good answers which show different ways to do a same thing. (2) When I want to perform a substitution, my attention gets concentrated on coming up with the search regex, and a search regex is more likely to trigger `/` rather than `:` in my brain. Apparently I am not the only one.

Comment: Is there a way to see what was previously featured in Hot Network Questions? Or am I misreading "history".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I wasn't going to post this beyond my comment but then I see it turned into a competition.* ;)

If you mistakenly enter `/%s/foo/bar/` when you actually want to run `:%s/foo/bar/` then you just need these eleven keystrokes:

```
q/kY:q<CR>:@0<CR>
```

Mapped:

```
nnoremap <F10> q/kY:q<CR>:@0<CR>
```

I guess I should explain. In the search history window (`q/`) we move to (`k`) and yank the line containing the last search with `Y` (short for `yy`). A yank without a register associated with it always goes to register `0`. Leaving the search history window (`:q<CR>`) for the the regular command line (`:`) we use the "execute register contents" command (`@`) with said register like so: `@0`. Execute it (`<CR>`) and you're done.

**A bit of background on why the (relatively) obvious solution won't work...**

Those who are aware that the most recently entered search pattern gets saved in register `/` may wonder, "Why can't you just transfer what was entered at the `/` prompt to the normal command line by dumping the `/` register there (i.e. `:<C-R>/<CR>`)?"

The problem is the slash between `%s` and `foo/bar/`. This fools Vim into thinking you are entering the command that has form `/{pattern}/{offset}<CR>` (see `:h search-commands`). As a result it interprets the text after that slash, i.e. `foo/bar/`, as an invalid entry for the `{offset}` part. Valid or invalid `{offset}` is never saved in the `/` register. Only `{pattern}` is. (Side note: `:h {offset}` shows valid values for that parameter.)

**Any workarounds?**

Well, if OP Quasimodo was in the habit of entering substitution commands with a valid separator other than `/` (e.g. `#` or `@`) then they never would have gotten themselves in this mess because their original thought to use `<C-R>/` would likely work then. ;)

Answer (score 7):

As B Layer said, Vim interprets the rest of the pattern (namely, `foo/bar.../`) as an invalid offset, so it throws that bit away.

I have found, however, an alternative:

- `q/` opens the complete search history in a new buffer, just as `q:` opens the command history.
- There I can yank the full last search term with `ky$`.
- `:q` closes the buffer window.
- `:<C-R>"` pastes the yanked pattern into the command line.

And here comes the obligatory mapping (here to <kbd>F10</kbd>) to make it easier.

```
nnoremap <F10> q/k"xy$:q<CR>:<C-R>x<CR>
```

It uses the register `x` so as not to mess with the default register.

Comment: one mapping option for yanking into a register (here I use `@s` as a mnemonic for "search" and `<leader>ys` as a mnemonic for "yank search") is `nnoremap <leader>ys :normal! q/k"syg_<cr>`

Answer (score 3):

This is probably even shorter:

```
cnoremap <C-X> <C-\>ehistget('/')<CR>
```

Comment: Very nice one! Also possible: `:<C-r>=histget('/')<CR>`, it might be easier to remember `<C-r>=` to enter an expression, rather than `<C-\>e` which is similar but probably more obscure to most.

Comment: Aha! Well, I see your 15 (keystrokes) and raise you...er...lower you 4. (To 11. See my answer.)  :)

Comment: What is this... [VimGolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/)? :-)

Comment: Headed that way. :)

Comment: Agreed with Filbranden, I actually thought the command was `ehistget` :D Confused readers may will want to read help `c_CTRL-\_e`.

Comment: I opted for c-mapping and `<C-\>e` fits better for it. But, of course, if one prefers conventional n-mapping then usual `<C-R>=` is okay too.